# resize divIcons (svgs) at zoom levels - Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, mapbox, svg, zoom, icon

I am adding a geoJSON to a map using a custom divIcon (from svg) for point markers with Leaflet.  The divIcon needs to resize on different zoom levels.  Currently I can see the icons and the popup works, but they do not resize (and actually, they are not anchored correctly either).  I have tried to reset the iconSize property on a zoom event, but that is not working; the zoom event is hit but the icon does not change.  I also tried to add multiple icons to each feature (points) in the geoJSON using the 'pointToLayer' function as described in the Leaflet docs, thinking that I could toggle the opacity at different zoom levels, but this does not work either (only one icon is added). How can I use divIcons that will resize?

some code snippets:

```js
geoJSONLayer = L.geoJson(newFeatures, {
//onEachFeature: onEachFeature,
pointToLayer: function (feature, latLng) {

    return new L.Marker(latLng, {
        icon: aDivIcon, clickable:false, opacity:1

      }).bindPopup(popupContent, popupOptions),
    new L.Marker(latLng, {
        icon: aDivIcon2, clickable:false, opacity:0

      }).bindPopup(popupContent, popupOptions); /// this doesn't work

  }
}).addTo(map);


var aDivIcon = L.divIcon({"iconSize": [12,12], "iconAnchor": Anchorvar,  "popupAnchor": Popupvar, html: '<svg class="marker-anIcon"><use xlink:href="#marker-anIcon"/></svg>'});
```

(event example)

```js
map.on('zoomend', function(e) {
   if (map.getZoom() === 15)  { 
        iconSize = [12,12];
        Anchorvar = [12,12] ;
        Popupvar = [ 0, -12]; 
    } 
...
}
```

Comment: Any chance you could use an [imageOverlay](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#imageoverlay) instead of a marker? Resizing a marker's icon with zoom would probably be quite tricky.

Comment: we are actually resizing a divICon on zooms that using the 2nd method I described above, but for a layer with a single feature, and that is not sourced from a geoJSON.  ...There will be hundreds of points; I am not sure an imageOverlay would be practical...also we need to use popups that render on a click, with properties for each point.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ve2huzxw/58/

Comment: I'll look ino that, but from what I see the images do not resize, and I am not sure how we would bind the needed properties to each feature..It doesn't seem to me that what I want to do should be that difficult? We have another layer added as a mapbox feature layer with divIcons that resize on zoom with no problems...but in the case there is no geoJSON involved.

Comment: Also, my co-worker reminded me that we need to dynamically change the color of the icons, so pngs won't work.

Comment: Using SVG is not an issue: http://jsfiddle.net/ve2huzxw/71/ By the way, source from GeoJSON should not be an issue either.

Answer (score 3):

You might need to actually change the div's themselves.

Something like

```
map.on('zoomend', function(e) {
   if (map.getZoom() === 15)  {      
      var elements = document.getElementsByClassName( 'icon-wrapper' );
      for (var i=0, max=elements.length; i < max; i++) {
        elements[i].style.width      = 8;
        elements[i].style.height     = 10;
        elements[i].style.marginLeft = 4;
        elements[i].style.marginTop  = 11;
      }
    } 
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case it should be useful to others, I wanted to resize markers on zoom so they remained roughly the same size on the ground (e.g. in kilometres): I did it using (more-or-less) this code:

```
map.on('zoomend', function() {
    const zoomLevel = map.getZoom();
    const iconSize = 2**zoomLevel;
    for (const marker of MyMap.markers) {
        const icon = marker.getIcon();
        icon.options.iconSize = [ iconSize, iconSize ];
        icon.options.iconAnchor = [ iconSize/2, iconSize/2 ];
        marker.setIcon(icon);
    }
});
```

It took a little investigation to realise I had to use `.options` to set `iconSize` & `iconAnchor`.