# Adding multiple divIcons to each point in a GeoJSON - Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, geojson, svg, zoom, icon

I am trying to add divIcons (SVGs) as markers to a point layer from a GeoJSON in a webapp using Leaflet.  I need to have different sized markers at different zoom levels.

I have asked related questions [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/172005/leaflet-jquery-cannot-add-or-remove-class-to-divicon-marker) and [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/171609/resize-divicons-svgs-at-zoom-levels-leaflet) in my attempts to simply resize the svg on a map zoom event, but this has proved harder than I thought (and harder than I think it should be). I would like to now try to add multiple markers to each point, and toggle their opacity at different zoom levels, but I don't see a clear way to do this.

Here is the code that constructs the map layer from a GeoJSON, and adds the icon:

```js
geoJSONLayer = L.geoJson(newFeatures, {
    pointToLayer: function(feature, latLng) {
        return new L.Marker(latLng, {
                icon: aDivIcon,
                clickable: false,
                opacity: 1
            }).bindPopup(popupContent, popupOptions),
            new L.Marker(latLng, {
                icon: aDivIcon2,
                clickable: false,
                opacity: 0    
            }).bindPopup(popupContent, popupOptions); /// adding a 2nd marker in this way doesn't work    
    }
}).addTo(map);


var aDivIcon = L.divIcon({
    "iconSize": [12, 12],
    "iconAnchor": Anchorvar,
    "popupAnchor": Popupvar,
    html: '<svg class="anIcon"><use xlink:href="#marker-anIcon"/></svg>'
});
```

I tried to swap the css class this way on a zoom event, but this leaves the old and new marker visible:

```
$(".icon14").attr("class", "icon14 icon15");
```

Comment: Instead of `$(".icon14").attr("class", "icon14 icon15");` shouldn't it be `$(".icon14").attr("class", "icon15");`? (Remove `icon14`)